# ¿Cómo crear una nueva variable condicionada a otras en R?

Tags: r, dataframe

si tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
    a    b    d 
   SI   HOY   1
   SI   AYER  2
   SI   <NA>  1
   NO   AYER  1
   SI   HOY   2
 <NA>   HOY   2
   NO   HOY   2
   NO   AYER  NA
```

Si deseo crear una nueva variable llamada **"cond"** que tome el valor de **`5`** siempre y cuando la columna `a` tome el valor de **`SI`** y la columna `b` tome el valor de **`AYER`**, adicionalmente, que tome el valor de **`10`** siempre y cuando la columna `a` sea igual a **`NO`** y la columna `b` sea igual a **`HOY`**, en otros casos que sea igual **`20`** y si hay un **`NA`** que tome el valor de **`NA`**.

El código que he realizado es el siguiente:

```
df$cond<-ifelse(df$a=="SI" & df$b=="AYER", 5,
         ifelse(df$a=="NO" & df$b=="HOY", 10,
         ifelse(df$a==""|df$b=="", NA, 20)))

df
```

Lo que me resulta en lo siguiente:

```
    a    b    d   cond
   SI   HOY   1    20
   SI   AYER  2    5
   SI   <NA>  1    NA
   NO   AYER  1    20
   SI   HOY   2    20
  <NA>  HOY   2    NA
   NO   HOY   2    10
   NO   AYER  NA   20
```

Mi pregunta es, cómo puedo hacer lo mismo pero con alguna otra función que me permita acortar código.

Ya que en mi base de datos real tengo que crear una variable que se crea con 15 condicionales como las que expresé anteriormente.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma interesante es usar la función `dplyr::case_when()`, vas a escribir un poco menos (no demasiado) pero sobre todo vas a ganar en claridad del código:

```
library("dplyr")

df %>% 
  mutate(
    cond = case_when( 
      a == "SI" & b == "AYER" ~ 5,
      a == "NO" & b == "HOY" ~ 10,
      TRUE ~ 20
    )
  )
```

Comentarios:

- Con el verbo `mutate()` creamos una nueva columna llamada `cond`
- Con `case_when()` establecemos las condiciones en la forma de `<condición> ~ <valor deseado>`, el valor default lo establecemos como `TRUE ~ 20`
- Las condiciones se evalúan según el orden que le hayas dado
- Asumo que conoces el operador pipe `%>%`, sino me dices.

Comment: He realizado el código, pero la condición de que si hay un **`NA`** no se cumple.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que `a = ""`  no verifica que sea `NA`, para chequear estos deberías hacer  `is.na(a)`

Comment: `df %>% 
  mutate(
    cond1 = case_when( 
      a == "SI" & b == "AYER" ~ 5,
      a == "NO" & b == "HOY" ~ 10,
      is.na(a) | is.na(b) ~ NA,
      TRUE ~ 20
    )
  )`

Realizo el siguiente código pero me resulta lo siguiente:

`Error: must be a double vector, not a logical vector`

Comment: Si coloco un valor distinto a NA en :

is.na(a) | is.na(b) ~ NA,

por ejemplo:

is.na(a) | is.na(b) ~ 8,

Se obtiene lo que la condición indica. 

Entonces, como asignar los `NA`?

Perdón, por tanto molestar. Espero su ayuda. 

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que `NA`  en realidad es un `NA` del tipo lógico, pero la nueva columna es numérica, para retornar explicitamente  este valor  usa `NA_real_`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Es de gran ayuda. Gracias, gracias, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar creando una tabla con las condiciones, ej

```
     SI NO NA
HOY   0 10 20
AYER  5  0 20
NA   20 20 20
```

Y luego usando una función que le asigne a cada fila del dataframe el valor de esa tabla de doble entrada, por ej

```
#El dataframe de tu ejemplo

df <- data.frame(
    rbind(
    c("SI", "HOY", 1),
    c("SI", "AYER", 2),
    c("SI", NA, 1),
    c("NO", "AYER", 1),
    c("SI", "HOY", 2),
    c(NA, "HOY", 2),
    c("NO", "HOY", 2),
    c("NO", "AYER", NA)
    ))

#La matriz con los casos

xx <- matrix(
    c(0,5,20,10,0,20, 20, 20,20), 
    ncol=3, nrow=3, 
    dimnames=list(
        c("HOY","AYER", "NA"),
        c("SI","NO","NA")
    ))

#La funcion que agrega la columna cond
#parametros
#d = dataframe del ejemplo
#c = matriz de condiciones
#coln = el nombre de la columna a agregar
#
#return = dataframe con la columna cond
f <- function(d, c, coln)
{

    for (i in 1:length(d$X1))
    {

    d[i,coln] <- c[ifelse(is.na(d[i,2]),"NA",as.character(d[i,2])), ifelse(is.na(d[i,1]),"NA",as.character(d[i,1]))]
    }
    return(d)
}

f(df, xx, "cond")
```

Después solo es cuestion de expandir la tabla de doble entrada con las condiciones adicionales y debería funcionar.

Saludos.

Comment: Interesante forma de hacerlo. Muchas gracias.